# Accessing a project's configure closure in Gradle

Tags: gradle

Is it possible to access the configure closure as defined by the api below from the Gradle build file of said project?

`Project project​(String path, Closure configureClosure)`

If not, then what purpose does the closure serve?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of this [function](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#project-java.lang.String-groovy.lang.Closure-) is to allow you to configure the project identified by the `path` parameter.

You can call this function in the same project as the build.gradle by doing:

```
project.project(path) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Also equivalent to:

```
configure(project) {
    // Do something here
}
```

Which is the same as simply editing your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: So if it's the same as editing my `build.gradle` file, then can I access a variable defined in this closure, but from within that project's dedicated `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @Vas I'm not sure what you're asking. The answer I gave assumes everything is being done in the same `build.gradle` corresponding to the project you wanted to configure which is why I said it is the same as editing the file. A closure's context by nature is not accessible outside the closure which is the point of calling it a **clos**ure. You can still access the project's properties from inside this closure, and therefore can change variables used in the project. If you want to create a property in the project, you can also use `project.ext`.